# Unable to copy and paste (or cut and paste) photos already reduced in size from Word document into an email

Tags: email, microsoft-word, photos

I cannot copy photos and paste them from a word document into the text of an email on my Sony Laptop having already substantially reduced the size of the photos using Microsoft Office Picture Manager.

I can readily manage to perform this function from  my work place PC but am presently working mostly from home. I am trying to email photos and text using a btinternet.com email address but have checked that I cannot perform the task using my alternate googlemail email address either. I can obviously highlight the relevant photographs but whenever I try to copy or cut them into the email text the paste function is disabled.

Comment: Simon, this is a programming site, your question would be better off elsewhere. Try www.superuser.com -- same format, different subject.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but based on your mention of gmail I have a feeling you are trying to copy and paste a picture into a webmail system.  I don't know of any web based systems that let you copy and paste photos, as far as I know this is not something a web browser supports.

What you want to do is 'attach' them to the message.  There should be a button for 'attach' or 'attachments' somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to paste it in a text-only email. Verify that your paste-destination is HTML capable.

Answer (score 0):

As @user23307 indicated, you can't cut and paste an image into Gmail.  However, there is an addon in the labs that will allow you to do so.  CLick on the green flask icon next to your email address in the upper right.  Enable the **Inserting images** feature.  This will allow you to upload an image into the email.